# How can I get Document Data and Reference Data at same time ?(Firestore, Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to get Document Data and Reference Data at the same time, and put data in to custom struct which consist with String Array.

When I run code below, only DocumentReference type "item1_" and "item2_" are appended.

Collection "section" has several documents. Each document has 2 Document references.
I can get right DocumentReference but I can't read it's data in same function.

How can I get both Data from Firestore?

```
    func getall_sec(top: String, mid: String){ref.collection("top_hierarchy").document(top).collection("mid_hierarchy").document(mid).collection("section").addSnapshotListener(){ (snap, err) in
        guard let docs = snap else {
            self.nosecs = true
            return
        }
        
        if docs.documentChanges.isEmpty{
            self.nosecs = true
            return
        }
        docs.documentChanges.forEach { (doc) in
         
            if doc.type == .added{

                let item1_ = doc.document.data()["item1"] as! DocumentReference
                let item2_ = doc.document.data()["item2"] as! DocumentReference


                item2_.getDocument(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        self.item2_name = querySnapshot?.data()?["low"] as! String
                        self.item2_ImageName = querySnapshot?.data()?["ImageName"] as! String
                    }
                }
                item1_.getDocument(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        self.item1_name = querySnapshot?.data()?["low"] as! String
                        self.item1_ImageName = querySnapshot?.data()?["ImageName"] as! String
                    }
                }

                self.sections.append(SectionModel(id: doc.document.documentID, item_name1: self.item1_name, item_ImageName1: self.item1_ImageName, item_name2: self.item2_name, item_ImageName2: self.item2_ImageName))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that getDocument is asynchronous and the the  self.sections.append code will actually execute before the code in the closures following the two get functions.

```
item2_.getDocument(){ (querySnapshot2, err2) in
   //this code will execute at some point
}
item1_.getDocument(){ (querySnapshot1, err1) in
   //this code will execute at some point
}

//this code will execute before the code in the two above getDocument closures.
self.sections.append(SectionModel(id: doc.document.documentID...
```

one solution is to nest the calls so they execute in order (this is not the best solution but demonstrates the concept)

```
item2_.getDocument(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
   item1_.getDocument(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
      self.sections.append(SectionModel(id: doc.document.documentID...
   }
}
```